# acts-as-taggable-onでMyタグを設定したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

acts-as-taggable-onでMyタグを設定しそのタグをつけられた投稿を表示したいのですが、２つ以上設定すると、表示されなくなってしまいます。複数個設定しても対応できるようにするには、どうしたら良いでしょうか。なにかわかる方は回答・コメントお願いしますm(_ _)m。

```
#myタグの設定はdeviseのアカウント編集ページでできるようになっています。

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

省略

  <%= text_field_tag 'user[tag_list]', resource.tag_list.join(","), placeholder: "タグ「,」で区切って複数のタグを入力できます" %>

  <div class="actions-edit">
    <%= f.submit "編集完了" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <%= link_to "戻る", :back, class: "linkto-edit" %>
```

```
@questions = Question.tagged_with("#{current_man.tag_list}").page(params[:page])
```

```
#表示
    <% @questions.each do |q| %>
        <hr>
        <div class="data">    
            <h3><%= q.title %></h3>
    <% end %>

<div class="bootstrap">
     <%= paginate @questions %>
</div>
```

Comment: もし質問が解決した場合は、解決に役立った回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックし、質問を解決済みにしていただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

`tagged_with("#{current_man.tag_list}")` のところで `tag_list` 全体を文字列にしたものと完全一致するタグを検索しようとしてしまっているので、 `tagged_with(current_man.tag_list)` のように配列のまま渡す必要があるようです。

`AND` 検索や `OR` 検索などの指定をしたい場合は https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#finding-tagged-objects に書いてあるように `tagged_with(current_man.tag_list, match_all: true)` や  `tagged_with(current_man.tag_list, any: true)` のようなオプションを指定してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。Question.tagged_with(current_man.tag_list, any: true).page(params[:page])で行けました！ありがとうございます。